# Cucumber works on Eclipse but not on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber

I am successfully running Cucumber test on my java/maven eclipse project. But when I add my project do Jenkins I always get the following error "cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at []".

I read in this thread [Setting cucumber-jvm options in Maven from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711189/setting-cucumber-jvm-options-in-maven-from-the-command-line) that:

> *...tests are running in separate JVM, so you need to specify that system property in the test plugin configuration (i.e. surefire or failsafe plugin config in your pom.xml)*

But I am not quite sure how to do this. Can anyone help me?

PS: I am using "cucumber-java" and "cucumber-junit" dependencies.

Comment: What maven goals and options are using in the jenkins build?

Comment: Is it just on Jenkins, or does the same failure happen when you build with Maven locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using surefire, the plugin documentation page http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html shows few options you can try to set system properties

For example you can try the **systemPropertyVariables** plugin settings

Answer (score 0):

do you see the feature files in your target folder on your Jenkins slave ? maybe your *.feature files get excluded because of an incorrect config of your resources exclusion/inclusion in Maven ?